# Powershell x64 does not start in Windows 8.1

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, nuget-package

The problem I need to be solved is that the Nuget Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2013 cannot start because the Windows Powershell raises the error:

**The shell cannot be started. A failure occurred during initialization: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.SessionStateScope' threw an exception.**

I tried reinstalling nuget, repairing VS2013, changing the execution policy in powershell x86 (the common solution given here in stackoverflow) but the error persists.

Until I realize that the problem is in the x64 powershell(C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0) because the x86 version is fine.

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 4 32-Bits in Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 is the 32bit version.

Comment: But exists a working powershell in C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

Comment: That would be the 64bit one.

Comment: Hum, thats weird, so @notjustme, are you telling me that the powershell in  System32 is the 64bit one and that the powershell in SysWOW64 is the 32bit one? In such case how can I fix it?

Comment: You don't, that's exactly how it's supposed to be.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64#Registry_and_file_system

Comment: Thanx, but I mean how can I fix the powershell in the SysWOW64 folder? (the subject of the question)

Comment: run DISM to detect and fix damaged Windows files : http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx

Comment: DISM says: No component store corruption detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer, it has to do with the legacy security policy in .Net

I open the file **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config** and set the attribute "enabled" to False in the tag **NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy** and voilá, the powershell of SysWoW64 is working.

Comment: this setting is not set by default. I just checked this on my system.

Comment: I don't know why the setting was set to true because I didn't change it, maybe it was caused by a Windows or .Net update. Indeed I found the solution looking for similar problems in the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was receiving this same error for an unknown reason and thanks to this hint I looked for the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy in

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

and

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

but could not find that tag...

I did see **LegacyCasPolicy enabled="true"** in

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

and set it to **false**...viola, worked like a charm...Had no idea of how this got set but could not find a solution to this problem anywhere, and no, I did not have any corrupted system files.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue different key.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

Change to false

```
NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"
```